# Should soap objects use constructor or setter for creation?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

When creating `JAXB` java objects for usage with `SOAP` webservices/jaxws, is it better - from the design point of view - to fill these objects by constructor, or by their setters?

Example:

```
@XmlRootElement
Customer {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;
    String birthdate;
    String notes;
    Address address;
}
```

Use either:

```
customer.setId(..);
customer.setName();
customer.setAge();
customer.setBirthdate();
customer.setNotes();
customer.setAddress();
```

or:

```
new Customer(12, "testname", 19, 2014-03-03, "test", new Address("streetname", 12345, "town"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB requires that you have a zero argument constructor (although it can be private).  Apart from that it doesn't matter how you populate your objects.

Comment: I know it doesn't *matter* for jaxb how I populate my fields, but maybe from the design point of view..